# How to display output of tasks of an Ansible playbook without using the '-v' option

Tags: ansible, yum

I have the following task to print out the current version of jenkins that is installed on some servers:

```
---
- hosts: all                                   
  remote_user: user                         
  tasks:
      - name: Printing the Jenkins version running on the masters
        yum:
          name: jenkins
        register: version

      - debug: var=version
```

I am trying to avoid using the `-v` option when running the playbook with hopes to keep the output as clean as possible.

If the playbook is run without the `-v` option the output looks like this:

```
TASK [Printing the jenkins version that is installed on each of the servers]***************
ok: [Server1]
ok: [Server2]
ok: [Server3]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************    ok: [Server1] => {
"changed": false, 
"version": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

ok: [Server1] => {
"changed": false, 
"version": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

ok: [Server1] => {
"changed": false, 
"version": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

However it returns that version is not defined. I am confused as to why this is happening because I have done the printing the same way for a bunch of other tasks without any problems. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check your ansible version. Works fine for me with 2.2.1

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov I'm using ansible 2.3 because that is the only version that the jenkins_script module works with. Besides for changing to Ansible 2.2.1 is there another workaround?

Comment: Why does the `debug` task run three times on `Server1`? Did you copy the transcript from the real output, or did you invent it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acheive this using the shell and debug

```
---
- hosts: all                                   
  remote_user: user
  become: True
  become_method: sudo      
  tasks:
      - name: Printing the Jenkins version running on the masters
        shell: cat /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml | grep '<version>'
        register: version

      - debug: var={{ version['stdout'] }}
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion worked. just had to change the debug task to: var=version.stdout_lines

Answer (score 1):

You can create ansible callback plugin, or use one available in network 
i.e.

[human_log](https://github.com/n0ts/ansible-human_log/blob/master/human_log.py)